# How do I make my stash function work? Every time I write "stash" it responds with "You have 0 Diamonds". Although I have ran mine several times

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
import random

Mine_time = 0
Mining = 0
Diamond = 0

def Mine(Mining):
    if Doing == "mine" or Doing == "Mine":
        Mining = random.randint(0, 10)
        print("you mined", Mining,"diamonds ")
    
def Stash(Mining, Diamond):
    if Doing == "Stash" or Doing == "stash":
      Diamond = Diamond + Mining
      print("You have", Diamond, "diamonds")

def Time(Mine_Time):
    if Doing == 'Time' or Doing == 'time':
        print('Your Time is:', Mine_time)

def MT(Mine_Time):
    if Mine_time > 0:
        print("this action is on cooldwon please wait", Mine_time, "seconds")


while True:
    Doing = input("\n")
    Mine(Mining)
    Stash(Mining, Diamond)
    Time(Mine_time)
    MT(Mine_time)
```

The possible commands are Stash, Mine, and Time, but time doesn't do anything yet. It would be very helpfull if every time I run Stash it didn't show "You have 0 Diamonds"

Comment: Because `Stash` has a parameter named `Diamond`, that means that `Diamond` starts out as a **local** variable with that value. Because of that, `Diamond = Diamond + Mining` will change that local variable, **not** the global one. You should study how variable scope works in Python, as well as how function calls work.

Comment: I suggest refactoring your code to use a class. Then all the member functions can set attributes on `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues, starting with concept and style and ending with the actual fulfillment of the task. I reworked your code so `Mine` and `Stash` work logically (leastwise for me).

**Disclaimer**: the code below is still wrong on multiple points, but I want to post it in this form in order to be understandable for OP.

```py
import random

Mine_time = 0
Mining = 0
Diamond = 0


def Mine():
    global Mining
    if Doing == "mine" or Doing == "Mine":
        Mined = random.randint(0, 10)
        print("you mined", Mined, "diamonds ")
        Mining += Mined


def Stash():
    global Diamond, Mining
    if Doing == "Stash" or Doing == "stash":
        Diamond = Diamond + Mining
        Mining = 0
        print("You have", Diamond, "diamonds")


def Time():
    if Doing == 'Time' or Doing == 'time':
        print('Your Time is:', Mine_time)


def MT():
    if Mine_time > 0:
        print("this action is on cooldown please wait", Mine_time, "seconds")


while True:
    Doing = input("\n")
    Mine()
    Stash()
    Time()
    MT()
```

What I've changed:

- Your global variables are now `global` inside your functions. So they keep their values between cycle's loops.
- `Mine` now firstly obtain random `Mined` value, this value shown to the user, and then it's added to `Mining`. So if you mined several times, you lose nothing.
- `Stash` now resets `Mining` to 0, so mined once wouldn't be added to stash several times.

Not sure how `Time` and `MT` should work, so I left them untouched.

What you should change (and also learn):

- General structure. If you have some data united with some logic, most probably it's a [class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). You have to learn what it is and how you should use it for tasks like this, and you wouldn't have such strange situations with variable scopes.
- [Function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) concept. Maybe you feel some things, but you definitely don't understand them.
- [Python code style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). [Here](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/intro-to-earth-data-science/write-efficient-python-code/intro-to-clean-code/python-pep-8-style-guide/) is quite easy to read intro.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will take your advice and apply it. I will also learn how to use functions.

Comment: @IanLuciano welcome to Stack Overflow :) If my answer helped you consider marking it as right.